# UIButton backgroundImage versus image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uibutton

I have UIButtons that I was trying to set the images to aspectFit.  However using Storyboards I ran into some difficulty I subclassed UIButton and programatically set the imageViews of the buttons to ScaleAspectFit

```
#import "UIButtonWithImageAspectFit.h"

@implementation UIButtonWithImageAspectFit

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    [self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
}

@end
```

This worked well and the buttons images display nicely.

However, now I have a need to swap out the images of the button programatically so I tried:

```
[_firstLetterButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2CeadLitir.png"]];
```

But this does not work so according to advise here I must use:

```
[_firstLetterButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"2CeadLitir.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

which adds the image as a backgroundImage to the button.  Now I have to images in the button.

1. that is scaled nicely as an image property of the button,
2. and another that is not scaled nicely as a background image displayed behind.

So I returned to the subclass of `UIButton` `UIButtonWithImageAspectFit`
and tried to change it so that it sets the contentMode of the backgroundImage rather than the image

But it does not seem to have a backgroundImage property that I can access but according to the documentation it does have

```
currentBackgroundImage
 Property
```

However I cannot use the same method `setContentMode` on that `currentBackgroundImage`

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to consider this illustration from Apple web-site.
[image]

It's from [Buttons tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIButton). In particular this:

> **State**
>   A button has four states to configure for appearance—default, highlighted, selected, and disabled.
>   And form

[UIButton class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage:forState:)

> **Discussion** 
>   In general, if a property is not specified for a state, the default is to use the UIControlStateNormal value. If the UIControlStateNormal value is not set, then the property defaults to a system value. Therefore, at a minimum, you should set the value for the normal state.

And here is [information about different UIControlState:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/UIControlStateNormal)

All this links is must-read for beginner iOS Developer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the UIButton has a method

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
        forState:(UIControlState)state
```

so All I needed to do was set the state when setting the image on the UIButton instead of on the UIButton.imageView